# Can not extract data from an simplexml object

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm getting an simplexml object from:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

If I do `dd($xml)` I get the following string in console:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#232
  +"Data": SimpleXMLElement {#240}
  +"Error": SimpleXMLElement {#241}
  +"xmlData": "<root><row><FiscalCode>27221245</FiscalCode><CompanyName>Nume Companie SRL</CompanyName><LegalForm>SRL</LegalForm><RegistrationNumber>J40/111/2010</RegistrationNumber><DateOfIncorporation>2010-07-29</DateOfIncorporation><Status>functiune;</Status><ShareCapital>1.510000000000000e+005</ShareCapital><NACE>6201</NACE><NACE_Descr>Activităţi de realizare a soft-ului la comandă (software orientat client)</NACE_Descr><PrimaryActivityVersion>2</PrimaryActivityVersion><NumberOfemployees>20</NumberOfemployees><County>Municipiul Bucuresti</County><City>BUCURESTI SECTORUL 5</City><Street>DR. JOSEPH LISTER</Street><Number>22</Number><Block /><Entrance /><Floor /><Apartment>1</Apartment><PostalCode>50543</PostalCode><PhoneNumber>0724063943</PhoneNumber><E-mail /><Web /><OwnershipForm /><CompanyIdentification>certificat de înmatriculare preschimbat; </CompanyIdentification><UpdateOn>2018-07-04</UpdateOn><Headquarters_DocumentType>Contract de închiriere</Headquarters_DocumentType><Headquarters_DocumentDuringType>Temporar</Headquarters_DocumentDuringType><Headquarters_DocumentNumber>1</Headquarters_DocumentNumber><Headquarters_DocumentDate>01-11-2016</Headquarters_DocumentDate><HeadquartersExpiryDayFrom>2016-11-01</HeadquartersExpiryDayFrom><HeadquartersExpiryDayUntil>2019-11-01</HeadquartersExpiryDayUntil><DateofIncorporationDocument>2018-07-03</DateofIncorporationDocument><SecondaryHeadquarters><row><Name>Punct de lucru</Name><StartDate /><StopDate /><Country>ROMANIA</Country><Locality>BUCUREŞTI SECTORUL 5</Locality><Street>DR.  STAICOVICI</Street><Number>19</Number><Block /><Entrance /><Floor>1</Floor><Apartment>2</Apartment><District>5</District><PostalCode /></row><row><Name>PUNCT DE LUCRU</Name><StartDate>2013-05-01 00:00:00.0000000</StartDate><StopDate>2014-05-01 00:00:00.0000000</StopDate><Country>ROMANIA</Country><Locality>BUCUREŞTI SECTORUL 5</Locality><Street>B-dul EROILOR</Street><Number>13</Number><Block /><Entrance /><Floor /><Apartment>2</Apartment><District>5</District><PostalCode /></row></SecondaryHeadquarters></row></root>"
}
```

Which the correct way to extract **FiscalCode**

I mention that 
`dd($xml->FiscalCode)` return nothing.

also

`dd($xml->root->row->FiscalCode);` does not work

The original xml is get from an external link:

It looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Data>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
            <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
    </Data>
    <Error />
    <xmlData>&lt;root&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;FiscalCode&gt;27225145&lt;/FiscalCode&gt;&lt;CompanyName&gt;Nume Companie SRL&lt;/CompanyName&gt;&lt;LegalForm&gt;SRL&lt;/LegalForm&gt;&lt;RegistrationNumber&gt;J40/7213/2010&lt;/RegistrationNumber&gt;&lt;DateOfIncorporation&gt;2010-07-29&lt;/DateOfIncorporation&gt;&lt;Status&gt;functiune;&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;ShareCapital&gt;1.510000000000000e+005&lt;/ShareCapital&gt;&lt;NACE&gt;6201&lt;/NACE&gt;&lt;NACE_Descr&gt;Activităţi de realizare a soft-ului la comandă (software orientat client)&lt;/NACE_Descr&gt;&lt;PrimaryActivityVersion&gt;2&lt;/PrimaryActivityVersion&gt;&lt;NumberOfemployees&gt;20&lt;/NumberOfemployees&gt;&lt;County&gt;Municipiul Bucuresti&lt;/County&gt;&lt;City&gt;BUCURESTI SECTORUL 5&lt;/City&gt;&lt;Street&gt;DR. JOSEPH LISTER&lt;/Street&gt;&lt;Number&gt;22&lt;/Number&gt;&lt;Block /&gt;&lt;Entrance /&gt;&lt;Floor /&gt;&lt;Apartment&gt;1&lt;/Apartment&gt;&lt;PostalCode&gt;50543&lt;/PostalCode&gt;&lt;PhoneNumber&gt;0724063943&lt;/PhoneNumber&gt;&lt;E-mail /&gt;&lt;Web /&gt;&lt;OwnershipForm /&gt;&lt;CompanyIdentification&gt;certificat de înmatriculare preschimbat; &lt;/CompanyIdentification&gt;&lt;UpdateOn&gt;2018-07-04&lt;/UpdateOn&gt;&lt;Headquarters_DocumentType&gt;Contract de închiriere&lt;/Headquarters_DocumentType&gt;&lt;Headquarters_DocumentDuringType&gt;Temporar&lt;/Headquarters_DocumentDuringType&gt;&lt;Headquarters_DocumentNumber&gt;1&lt;/Headquarters_DocumentNumber&gt;&lt;Headquarters_DocumentDate&gt;01-11-2016&lt;/Headquarters_DocumentDate&gt;&lt;HeadquartersExpiryDayFrom&gt;2016-11-01&lt;/HeadquartersExpiryDayFrom&gt;&lt;HeadquartersExpiryDayUntil&gt;2019-11-01&lt;/HeadquartersExpiryDayUntil&gt;&lt;DateofIncorporationDocument&gt;2018-07-03&lt;/DateofIncorporationDocument&gt;&lt;SecondaryHeadquarters&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Punct de lucru&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;StartDate /&gt;&lt;StopDate /&gt;&lt;Country&gt;ROMANIA&lt;/Country&gt;&lt;Locality&gt;BUCUREŞTI SECTORUL 5&lt;/Locality&gt;&lt;Street&gt;DR.  STAICOVICI&lt;/Street&gt;&lt;Number&gt;19&lt;/Number&gt;&lt;Block /&gt;&lt;Entrance /&gt;&lt;Floor&gt;1&lt;/Floor&gt;&lt;Apartment&gt;2&lt;/Apartment&gt;&lt;District&gt;5&lt;/District&gt;&lt;PostalCode /&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;Name&gt;PUNCT DE LUCRU&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;StartDate&gt;2013-05-01 00:00:00.0000000&lt;/StartDate&gt;&lt;StopDate&gt;2014-05-01 00:00:00.0000000&lt;/StopDate&gt;&lt;Country&gt;ROMANIA&lt;/Country&gt;&lt;Locality&gt;BUCUREŞTI SECTORUL 5&lt;/Locality&gt;&lt;Street&gt;B-dul EROILOR&lt;/Street&gt;&lt;Number&gt;13&lt;/Number&gt;&lt;Block /&gt;&lt;Entrance /&gt;&lt;Floor /&gt;&lt;Apartment&gt;2&lt;/Apartment&gt;&lt;District&gt;5&lt;/District&gt;&lt;PostalCode /&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/SecondaryHeadquarters&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</xmlData>
</Result>
```

I get the link like that:

```
       $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://wsprokolekt.rocomp.ro/service.asmx/CompanyGeneralInformation?idUser=*****&CUI=******',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
            ));

            $data = curl_exec($curl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

Thank you for you time!

Comment: show the source xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read and decode xmlData and then get FiscalCode

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$xml1 = simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode($xml->xmlData));
echo $xml1->row->FiscalCode;
```

Comment: Thank you splah58 I'm much closer but $xml1->row->FiscalCode return also an 
simpleXML object: SimpleXMLElement {#228
  +0: "27221245"
}
 how do I extract "27221245"?

Comment: $string = (string) $simplxmlObject;

Comment: Is there a way to load in an array all the data from xml1 with a foreach() loop?